# Sum of Two Squares Why not others

Tags: elementary-number-theory

So why can some integers be written as the sum of two squares:
For example: $5 = 4 + 1$ and $100 = 64 + 36$.
Why aren't some others like these. Why 7, 19, and 1295 are not the sums of squares. Can someone prove why this is true?

I feel like the number 4 has something to do with it.

My suggested proof:
We have the sum of two integer squares: $S = a^2 + b^2$

Since their sum is odd, one must be odd and the other must be even.

Let: $a = 2m$ and $b = 2n + 1$ for integers $m$ and $n$.

Then: $S = (2m)^2 + (2n + 1)^2 = 4m^2 + 4n^2 + 4n + 1 = 4(m^2 + n^2 + n) + 1$

Hence, if the sum of two squares is odd, it is one more than a multiple of 4.

And none of {7, 19, 1295} is of the form $4k + 1$.

Comment: What exactly do you want to prove?

Comment: @barakmanos That 7, 19, and 1295 are not the sums of squares

Comment: How do you know that $7$ is not the sum of two squares?

Comment: Because I tried to do it and it doesn't work

Comment: Good, so you've just proved it (to be more accurate, you should show that the sum of $1$ and $4$ is not $7$, but I assume that you've already done that).

Comment: Yes but I want a general proof as to why some integers cannot be written as the sum of two squares.

Comment: In order to prove that **some** integers cannot be written as the sum of two squares, you need to show that at least one such integer exists, which you have, so there's your proof.

Comment: As a side-note, you should rethink exactly what you want to ask, and then rephrase the question, because no proof is required here besides what you've already done.

Comment: Your proof that no number equivalent to $3 \pmod 4$ is expressible as the sum of two squares is correct.  It is not the end of the road, however, as $57=3 \cdot 19 \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ is not expressible as the sum of two squares.

Comment: @RossMillikan Yes, but it is true for 7,19,and 1295, right?

Comment: Yes, it is correct for them.

Answer (score 2):

$7$ and $19$ are not expressible as the sum of two squares because they are odd primes and they do not leave a remainder $1$ upon division by $4$ (using [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_theorem_on_sums_of_two_squares))

How did you know that $1295$ is not? Anyway, due to Fermat:

A number is expressible as a sum of $2$ squares if and only if in its prime factorization, every prime of the form $4k+3$ occurs an even number of times.

Comment: Is my suggested proof correct?

Comment: What you had shown is precisely:

If an odd number is expressible as the sum of two squares, then it is one more than a multiple of $4$.

Comment: so is that correct